# Start Activity on a thread

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a `Splash Activity`. and I want to start a new Activity when the progressStatus reach its max value. My problem is i dont know where to locate the start intent. I have an error on my `IF statement`.

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                while (progressStatus < 100) {
                progressStatus += 5;

                }   
                if (progressStatus == progressBar.getMax()) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(".MENU");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                // Update the progress bar and display the
                // current value in the text view
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                        textView.setText(progressStatus + "/"
                                + progressBar.getMax());
                    }
                });

                try {
                    // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.
                    // Just to display the progress slowly

                    Thread.sleep(200);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

    }).start();
```

on my **manifest**:

```
<activity
android:name="NewMainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:screenOrientation="portrait">
<intent-filter>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <action android:name=".MENU" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

My Splash activity is `MainActivity Class` then `NewMainActivity Class` is the second activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to check the while loop as simply as this

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (progressStatus < 100) {
           progressStatus += 5;
           // Update the progress bar and display the 
           //current value in the text view
           handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                   textView.setText(progressStatus+"/"+progressBar.getMax());
                }
            });

            try {
               // Sleep for 200 milliseconds. 
               //Just to display the progress slowly
               Thread.sleep(200); 
               if (progressStatus == 100){
                   Intent intent = new Intent(".MENU");
                   startActivity(intent);
               }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         } // while loop
      } // run()
  }).start();
```

then under the `Thread.sleep()` put your condition.

Answer (score 11):

You have to call the startActivity(intent) from the UI thread. You can just create a new method like the following:

```
public void startActivityFromMainThread(){

   Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
   handler.post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
      public void run() {
          Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, NewMainActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
      }
   });
}
```

The Looper.getMainLooper() verifies that this will be executed on the Main thread.

Then your code will look like this:

```
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
            progressBar.setMax(100);
            progressStatus = 0;

            while (progressStatus < 100) {
               progressStatus += 5;            

               // Update the progress bar and display the
               // current value in the text view
               handler.post(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                      textView.setText(progressStatus + "/"
                              + progressBar.getMax());
                  }
               });


             try {
                 // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.
                 // Just to display the progress slowly

                 Thread.sleep(200);

              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
           }
           startActivityFromMainThread();
        }

}).start();
```

Comment: sir the logcat says that `unable to find explicit activity class`

Comment: @user3698267 what is the name of the Activity class which you wants to start ? and is it specified in manifest ?

Comment: @user3698267 on the code above you have to replace the MenuActivity with the name of the activity that you want to start. If that's "Menu" for example you have to name it as : Menu.class

Comment: sir it works. but the location of startActivity seems not correct. because once I start the game the progressStatus is already in its max length

Comment: @user3698267 Also keep in mind that if something works, you can give an upvote or accept the answer.

Comment: sir. the splash activity is not showing. it jumps on the SecondActivity as I start Application

Comment: Then it seems that there is a problem with the ProgressBar. Try to debug it, to see how updates and when the **progressStatus >= 100**

Comment: I already figured out the answer. it is under the while loop. lol. thank you guys !

Comment: @user3698267 OK, if my answer has helped you to solve the problem you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Just Send empty message to Handler when progress reached to max level.From run u cant directly start activity . you need to do it in ui thread

```
private Handler handlerIntentStart = new Handler() {

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.os.Handler#handleMessage(android.os.Message)
         */
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            // ****** Acitity class must be added in manifest
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    NewMainActivity.class));
        }

    };


new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) {
                progressStatus += 5;

                if (progressStatus == progressBar.getMax()) {
                    handlerIntentStart.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }
                // Update the progress bar and display the
                // current value in the text view
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                        textView.setText(progressStatus + "/"
                                + progressBar.getMax());
                    }
                });

                try {
                    // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.
                    // Just to display the progress slowly

                    Thread.sleep(200);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }).start();
```

Comment: starting the next activity seems to work but the problem is the the splash activity is not showing.

Comment: @user3698267 it is showing bt the problem may b sleep time u gve very less .. and its now withing while loop

Answer (score 0):

Use Explicit Intent.

```
if (progressStatus == progressBar.getMax()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

EDIT: Try like this

```
if (progressStatus == progressBar.getMax()) {
     Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
     handler.post(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
         }
     });
}
```