# Starting an Activity from Runnable()

Tags: java, android

Hopefully not a dupe, dug around as best I could and came up with nothing. All the suggestions in SO when I typed the title had less than 0 upvotes, so hopefully I'm not following the same path. My question, essentially, is what will happen if I do this on my main thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });
            }
        }).start();
```

Assuming `i` is an `intent`, that I didn't screw anything else up, etc. Obviously this is a very trivial case. But I'm wondering if there's anything I need to do to/on the worker thread? Am I going to cause a memory leak or other issue if I do this? Do I need to make a call to something on the worker thread to tell it that I no longer need it? Will it understand on its own that it's no longer needed? Am I just completely misunderstanding something? Thanks!

Comment: maybe this answer has some thing to answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089803/start-activity-on-a-thread if not let me know i give it a shot when i have time.

Comment: Not really...I understand HOW to do it, just not the implications.

Comment: Is the Runnable that immediately calls `runOnUiThread()` for demonstration purposes only?

Comment: Yeah...in practice there's a lot of other stuff that the Runnable does, but then I get to a point based on the work done that I'd like to start a new activity based on the results of that work that's already been done.

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not sure if that is going to work. But if you will go this way you might get memory leaks.

You can achieve activity creation posting an event from asynctask https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus 
, and subscribing to that event in your activities/fragments. You can create base class for multiple activities and subscribing inside it. So you will get event anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

A java Thread will become Dead after finishing execution. You will have a short memory leak until the thread finishes it's task (because the thread is bound to the current activity and that activity is not destroyed until you finish your stuff).

Anyway I would suggest you to use AsynkTask if you want to update the ui after some background task.

If you are more advanced the best solution would be to use RxJava or Live Data. In android we don't use Thread too often since we have other wrappers that ease our communication between threads