# because of Thread my intent is not starting

Tags: android, android-intent, thread-sleep

What's wrong with the code? I can't find any errors and the splash screen won't get dispose and the intent is not working because of it. I tried a different code for this splash screen it's working without any problem. I just want to know why this code is not working.

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle sScreen) {
        super.onCreate(sScreen);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void Run(){
                try{
                    sleep(1000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.projects.ziham.learning.STARTINGPOINT");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

and I changed intent parameters its also not working example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this,StartingPoint.class);
```

Comment: this code is perfect and im sorry i have use Run() instead is run()... anyway big thanks to everyone who took effort to help me . sorry if  wasted your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, StartingPoint.class));
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: this method its working .. but can i know why my code is not working

Comment: @MohamedZiham its `run` not `Run` like `@Override
            public void run() {`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following to redirect after some time delay

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                       Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, yourActivity.class);
                       startActivity(i);
                      finish();
               }
           }, 1000);
```

Please try this

```
    Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("run called");
             try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                System.out.println("finally called");
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
```

Comment: this code is starting the intent but splash screen is not working .. any way a big thanks to you i found my error.... i have use Run() instead of run .. its a typo ...

Comment: glad to help you, can you please mark as a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Timer` you can use `Handler`.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
             Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, StartingPoint.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
             }
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

So from your code, it's a pretty fair assumption to assume this is acting as a splash screen.

While there are now several answers to fix your intent not starting, [this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) article demonstrates the correct way to implement splash screens.

Credit: [Big Nerd Ranch](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/)

Comment: yes its a splash screen .. i fixed it but can i know whats wrong with this code ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089803/start-activity-on-a-thread notice how they have used a Runnable within their Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to use `postDelayed` method found in `Handler`, or you need to run the `startActivity` in a UIThread:

```
runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.projects.ziham.learning.STARTINGPOINT");
    startActivity(intent); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace Run into run in your code and also Use Handler.

```
Thread timer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }


    });
timer.start();
```